# Node Program Hangs

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I have a simple Node program that is designed to query a database table using Knex.js, iterate through the results and move onto the next process. The problem I am running into is that the program just hangs and doesn't exit the terminal. Here is the code:

```
const knex = require('knex');

db = knex({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: `connectionString`
})

db.raw(`
    select * from tablename;
    `).then((resp) => {
       console.log(resp.rows);
       resp.rows.forEach((element => {
           console.log(element)
            }))
    })
```

I have tried adding an additional .then(process.exit()) on the promise chain, but when I do that, it ends up killing the process before I'm able to do what needs done next.

What can I do to cleanly exit this process after the program has run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote

> I have tried adding an additional .then(process.exit())

So I imagine the resulting code is

```
db.raw(`
select * from tablename;
`).then((resp) => {
   console.log(resp.rows);
   resp.rows.forEach((element => {
       console.log(element)
        }))
}).then(process.exit())
```

If so, you are not using the `then` function correctly, because [it wants a function as argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then?retiredLocale=it).

You can fix it in this way:

```
db.raw(`
select * from tablename;
`).then((resp) => {
   console.log(resp.rows);
   resp.rows.forEach((element => {
       console.log(element)
        }))
}).then(() => process.exit()) // look at this line
```

Or even better for readability, I would consider the usage of `async/await`:

```
const knex = require('knex');

db = knex({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: `connectionString`
});

(async => {
    const resp = await db.raw(`select * from tablename;`)
    resp.rows.forEach((element => {
        console.log(element)
    }))
    process.exit(0)
})()
```